# Json web token generation in angular4 or javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, jwt

How can I generate JSon web token for a user who just login into the application in angular2/4 application

Comment: What are you going to use web token for? If you are simulating user login with back-end API that job `token generation` is done in the back-end not front-end.

Answer (score 2):

generating a token is a back-end side job and angularJs should just store it and send it to server to validate user data and basically generating it in front-end isn't a good idea cos you'r key will get in people's hand and they can generate tokens with it that server will validate it as True and it will make problems and error's for application.

Answer (score 2):

You can't generate web token from client side. Please use https://jwt.io/ to use it in your own server side language and use https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt this library to consume it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there are number of way by using you can create JSON web token for your app, for example using `btoa` approach , or using `jwt.io` etc.

> But Why to generate JSON web token ?

Generally JSON web token should be generated from back end side and which is safe also, so don't try this on client side.